# ¿Existe alguna manera de crear clases de forma dinámica en C#?

Tags: c#, class, map, clase-abstracta

Me pregunto si existe alguna forma de crear clases de forma dinámica.

Lo que me gustaria hacer es algo asi como un mapeado y que se vayan añadiendo miembros dinamicamente a una clase principal.

Todas las clases creadas dinamicamente comparten la misma estructura (clase prototipo), lo único que cambiaría sería el nobre de la clase y el nombre del constructor. Y una sola función que sería virtual o un delegado que es la única que necesito cambiar su comportamiento.

Algo asi sería lo que estoy pensando:

//--------------------------------------------------------

```
public class ClaseBase
{
      public ClaseBase(Tipo1 var1, Tipo2 var2)
      {
      }

      public virtual void Execute()
      {
      }   
}
```

//--------------------------------------------------------

```
public class Copia1 : ClaseBase
{
      public Copia1(Tipo1 var1, Tipo2 var2) : base(var1, var2)
      {
      }

      public override void Execute()
      {
          Delegado1();
      }
}
```

//--------------------------------------------------------

Y lo que me gustaría es que se generara una clase como esta:

```
public class MainClass
{
      Copia1 copia1;
      Copia2 copia2;
      .............
      CopiaN copiaN;

      Tipo1 var1;
      Tipo2 var2;

      public MainClass()
      {
          copia1 = new Copia1(var1, var2);
          copia2 = new Copia2(var1, var2);
          .............
          copiaN = new CopiaN(var1, var2);
      }
}
```

//--------------------------------------------------------

No me importa que sea todo "virtual" mientras consiga ese comportamiento.

Lo ideal sería mapearlo por ejemplo con un diccionatrio y que el método que busco se encarge de   generar la clase principal (y las clases copia).

Algo asi:

```
Dictionary map = new Dictionary<NombreClaseCopia, Delegate>();
map.Add(Copia1, Delegado1);
map.Add(Copia2, Delegado2);
map.Add(CopiaN, DelegadoN);

ClassMakerMethod(map);
```

Como digo, no me importa que todo ocurra en memoria, no tiene que estar fisicamente escrito en un archivo, lo que si me interesa es que tenga ese comportamiento y funcione como una clase genuina en todos los aspectos.

¿Sería posible hacer algo así?
Muchas gracias!!

Comment: No es un interfaz lo que buscas?

Comment: No creo... lo que busco es evitar tener que escribir 30 clases practicamente iguales en 30 archivos diferentes... si pudiera hacer lo que digo con uno o dos archivos sería suficiente... Acabo de encontrar esto pero parece chino mandarín XD... ¿Me recomendarías alguno de estos metodos?¿Me interesa que sea lo mas estandar posible? Es para un juego... no me gustaría que a la hora de compilar no me funcionara en alguna plataforma como Android, Linix, Mac o lo que sea... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862226/how-to-dynamically-create-a-class

Comment: Para hacer eso deben haber patrones de diseño, por lo pronto revisa este link https://www.fixedbuffer.com/la-potencia-de-la-reflexion-puede-ser-la-solucion/

Comment: Revisa este tambien https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Japv!!

Comment: Yo tal vez no entiendo tu pregunta, sigo sin ver exactamente cual sería el caso de uso, y no termino de entender que beneficios generaria crear dinamicamente las clases (aunque sería posible mediante reflection). Tal vez si pones un ejemplo mas "real" ajustado a lo que necesitas sea capaz de entenderlo y darte alguna alternativa :) No te serviría por ejemplo tener solo una clase, y que reciba un `Action` si lo unico que varía es una funcion a ejecutar?

Comment: Si, verás. Es para una "maquina de estados finitos". Funciona parecido a un sémaforo en programación concurrente. La clase Main es como un switch que se encarga de cambiar los estados y se basa en las instacias de las clases de estado para ello. Luego cada estado debe estar en una clase diferente y ser derivada de una clase comín llamada "State" por ejemplo. Los estados pueden ser (correr, saltar, atacar...) el caso es que en la mayoria de los estados rara vez escribo mas de 10 lineas y todo en la misma función. Por eso si pudiera crearlas dinamicamente y sustitur solo esa funcion sería genial

Comment: Revisa los patrones de diseño Abstract Factory o Prototype, quizá alguno de ellos te sirva en la tarea que buscas.

Comment: Lo miraré!! Muchas gracias HeyJhon!!